# Changing join/quit message colors in irssi

Tags: irssi

I want to customize a theme in irssi to reduce the noise that joins/quits create in an IRC channel. I want the entire join/quit line (nick has joined/left) in dark gray, so that it is almost invisible againt a black background. How is this accomplished by editing the theme file?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: @Sybren I ended up just hiding those message using: /ignore -channels #chan1,#chan2,#chan3 * JOINS PARTS QUITS NICKS

Comment: hmmm not exactly what I want, but thanks for giving me at least some compromise.